# Building MySQL plugin for QT 5.7

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, dll

So I'm try to build the MySQL plugin for qt 5.7 on Windows. I managed to generate the qmysqld.dll an qmysql.dll by doing the following

**1**) Downloading Qt source files 
**2**) Navagating to `QTDIR\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers` and running qmake on the qsqldriver.pro file while linking both mySql\include and mySql\libmysql.lib. Specifically I ran the following command:

```
qmake "INCLUDE+=mysql-5.7.17-win32\include" "LIBS+=C:\mysql-5.7.17-win32\lib\libmysql.lib" -o MakeFile mysql.pro
```

**3**) Running `mingw32-make` to compile the project. 
**4**)I then moved both qmysqld.dll and qmysql.dll from `QTDIR\plugins\sqldrivers` to `ACTUALQTINSTALLATION\mingw53_32\plugins\sqldrivers`
The files were already there and needed to be replaced.

This is the test code I'm trying to run.

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL", "my_sql_db");
    db.setHostName("localhost");
    db.setDatabaseName("test");
    db.setUserName("root");
    db.setPassword("");

    if(!db.open())
        qDebug() << db.lastError().text();
```

Which produces the following error, as it did before I built the plugins.

```
"Driver not loaded Driver not loaded"
Driver:  ("QSQLITE", "QMYSQL", "QMYSQL3", "QODBC", "QODBC3", "QPSQL", "QPSQL7")
```

The only thing I can think of is that I ran the DependencyWalker program on qsqlmysqld.dll and it's saying that LIBMYSQL.dll, QT5CORED.dll and QT5SQLD.dll are missing and that pretty much every other dependency is for an x64 bit architecture(As opposed to qsqlmysql.dll which is 32). I know very little about what that means and it's my first time using DependencyWalker but would this indicate that I've somehow built the dll to be 32 bit and need to recompile it as a 64 bit and that should solve the issue?

Very confused about this, I've been trying to get this to work on and off for over a month now.

Comment: 64 bit processes can not load 32 bit DLLs.